Missing Components ( TSQLScriptParser, TSshTunnel ) from talend Palette
I tried with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration Kit version (8.0) and also with (version 7.3.1) and i have the same problem (Missing components in talend palette)
I downloaded version 8 of Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. However, when importing a Talend project, an error occurred: "Some components were not loaded, such as tSQLScriptParser and TSshTunnel." These two components are missing from the palette. I encountered the same error with version 7.3.1. How can I resolve this issue?

Hi I think, those two components are custom components and aren't available by default in talend studio, have you tried create an empty project and install them before importing your project ?
